# Porque salen estos errores?

Tags: c++, pilas

Codigo de la clase "linkedStackType"

```
#define LINKEDSTACKTYPE_H
#ifndef LINKEDSTACKTYPE_H
#endif
#include "NodoStack.h"
#include <cassert>

template < class TYPE > class linkedStackType {
public:
    bool isEmptyStack() const;
    bool isFullStack() const;
    void initializeStack();
    void push(const TYPE &newItem);

    TYPE top() const;
    void pop();
    linkedStackType();
    ~linkedStackType();

private:
    NodoStack< TYPE > *stackTop;

};

template < class TYPE> linkedStackType < TYPE > ::linkedStackType() {
    stackTop = NULL;
}
```

Codigo de la clase main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include "linkedStackType.h"
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void evaluarExpresionPostfija(string, linkedStackType < int >&, int &);
string conv_postfija(string &, string &);

int prioridad(char);
bool operador(char operador);
bool operando(char);

int main()
{  
    string exp_infija, exp_postfija = "";
    cout << "INGRESE EXPRESION INFIJA: ";
    getline(cin, exp_infija);

    conv_postfija(exp_infija, exp_postfija);
    cout << "EXPRESION POSTFIJA" << exp_postfija << endl;

    int resultado;
    linkedStackType <int> enteros;
    evaluarExpresionPostfija(exp_postfija, enteros, resultado);
    cout << "EL RESULTADO ES :  " << resultado << endl;

    return 0;
}

void evaluarExpresionPostfija(string expostfija, linkedStackType <int>& stack, int&valor) {
    int numero;
    stack.initializeStack();

    if (!expostfija.empty()) {
        while (!expostfija.empty()) {
            char indice = expostfija.at(0);
            expostfija = expostfija.substr(1, expostfija.length());
            string caracter = "";
            caracter += indice;

            if (operando(indice)) {
                numero = atoi(caracter.c_str());
                stack.push(numero);
            }
            if (operador(indice)) {
                int op2 = stack.top();
                stack.pop();

                if (stack.isEmptyStack()) {
                    cout << "EXPRESION INCORRECTA" << endl;
                    exit(1);
                }
                int op1 = stack.top();
                stack.pop();

                switch (indice) {
                   case '+': stack.push(op1 + op2);
                    break;
                   case '-': stack.push(op1 - op2);
                    break;
                   case '*': stack.push(op1*op2);
                       break;
                   case '/':
                       if (op2 != 0)
                           stack.push(op1 / op2);
                       else {
                           cout << "No se puede dividir entre cero" << endl;
                           exit(1);
                       }
                       break;
                   case '^': stack.push(int(pow(op1, double(op2))));
                       break;


                }
            }
        }//end while(expostfija.empty())
        valor = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
    }//endif


}
//-----------------------------
string conv_postfija(string&E_inf, string &E_post) {
    linkedStackType <char> postfija;
    char caracter;
    postfija.push('(');
    E_inf += ')';

    while (!postfija.isEmptyStack()) {
        caracter = E_inf.at(0);
        E_inf = E_inf.substr(1, E_inf.length());

        if (operando(caracter))
            E_post += caracter;
        if (caracter=='(')
            postfija.push(caracter);

        if (operador(caracter)) {
           if(operador(postfija.top()))
               while (prioridad(caracter) <= prioridad(postfija.top())) {
                   char arg = postfija.top();
                   E_post += arg;
                   postfija.pop();
                   if (!operador(postfija.top()))
                       break;
               }
           postfija.push(caracter);
        }
        if (caracter == ')') {
            while (postfija.top() != '(') {
                E_post += postfija.top();
                postfija.pop();
            }//endwhile
            return E_post;
        }

    }


}//endstring
//---------------------------------------------
int prioridad(char oper) {
    int prioridad = 0;
    if (operador(oper)) {
        switch (oper) {
        case '^': prioridad = 3;
            break;
        case '/': prioridad = 2;
            break;
        case '*': prioridad = 2;
            break;
        case '+': prioridad = 1;
            break;
        case '-': prioridad = 1;
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Donde me salen estos errores al momento de compilar:

> Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
>   Error   C2143   error de sintaxis: falta ';' delante de '<' Final   c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\final\final\linkedstacktype.h  20
>
> Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
>   Error   C4430   falta el especificador de tipo; se presupone int. Nota: C++ no admite default-int   Final   c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\final\final\linkedstacktype.h  20
>
> Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
>   Error   C2238   símbolos (token) inesperados delante de ';' Final   c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\final\final\linkedstacktype.h  20

Me base en un tutorial de YT y copie el codigo tal cual se muestra ahi, paso a paso, por eso no entiendo esos errores cuando me ponen sobre el "NodeStack" el error en la sintaxis, el tutorial venia asi como lo estan viendo en el codigo y compilaba. Asi que no se que podria ser el error o si alguien me pudiera orientar.

Comment: Estas usando el mismo compilador y la misma version ?

Comment: Sí, el compilador es visual studio. La versión es la 2015.

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo del NodoStack ?

Comment: En el tutorial que segui no mostraban el NodoStack, asi que no tiene codigo dentro del header. Igual podria ser eso, alguna idea de como iria ese codigo?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LINKEDSTACKTYPE_H
#ifndef LINKEDSTACKTYPE_H
#endif
#include "NodoStack.h"
#include <cassert>
```

Las tres primeras líneas del código de arriba se denominan *guarda* y sirven para evitar que una cabecera se importe varias veces (lo que provoca problemas porque de cara al compilador los símbolos aparecerán definidos e incluso puede que implementados varias veces.

El problema aquí es que estás usando incorrectamente la *guarda*. La *guarda* debe encapsular **toda** la cabecera, mientras que tu *guarda* no está encapsulando absolutamente nada. Debería quedar así:

```
// Si no esta definido el simbolo...
#ifndef LINKEDSTACKTYPE_H 

// lo definimos
#define LINKEDSTACKTYPE_H

// Ahora incluimos todo el codigo del archivo
#include "NodoStack.h"
#include <cassert>

template < class TYPE > class linkedStackType {
// ...

// Y al final de la cabecera cerramos la guarda
// El comentario facilita la lectura del código cuando hay varias
// directivas del precompilador en el fichero
#endif // LINKEDSTACKTYPE_H
```

Para documentar el resto de problemas sería necesario que mostrases la declaración de la clase `NodoStack`

Comment: No tengo el de NodoStack, dado que el tutorial que seguí no mostraba ese pedazo de código.

Comment: @D.Hazard Si no tienes esa clase no podrás compilar ese código de ninguna manera